# preg_match no match if there is something after the /

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to use `preg_match` for certain kinds of URLs. I just want to have a match if there is nothing after `/blog/`, so `/blog/foo` should be not matched.

```
preg_match("/^(http:\/\/)?([^\/]+)?(\/blog\/)/i", 'http://example.com/blog/', $matches)
```

How can I make it only match if there is nothing after `/blog/`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just search for end of the string after /blog/ :

```
(preg_match('%.*?/blog/$%', $subject)
```